# HTML to jsx converter not preserving css units

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'm using the HTML to JSX converter of react.js which is demonstrated here:

https://magic.reactjs.net/htmltojsx.htm

and noticed an odd behaviour.

when translating this code:

```
<div style="font-size: 14px; line-height: 14px">Hello world</div>
```

the translation within the return phrase is:

```
<div style={{ fontSize: 14, lineHeight: 14 }}>Hello world</div>
```

Notice that the "px" was dropped. Now while this is fine with the "fontSize" feature, the "lineHeight" in css acts completely different, and line-height of 14 is not equivalent at all to 14px.

Any suggested workarounds or explanations will be highly appreciated.

Comment: See update below. Might be of interest to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known behavior and probably a bug. Though, the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height) discourages the use of use of unit-specified values for `line-height`.

Because you have already specified `font-size` for that element (and since it parses it correctly) you really don't need to use `px`-values for your `line-height`, because it will then refer to the elements' `font-size` property.

> The used value is this unitless `number` multiplied by the element's font size. The computed value is the same as the specified `number`. In most cases **this is the preferred way** to set line-height with no unexpected results in case of inheritance.

Instead, just do:

```
<div style="font-size:14px; line-height:1">Hello world</div>
```

This should have the same effect as to setting `line-height` to 14px.

**Edit:**

It seems like you can circumvent the issue by instead having `14px !important`. Just in case you *really* need to use `px`.

---

### UPDATE March 8 2016

As of React v15.0 you should no longer be facing this issue. As per the [changelog](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2016/03/07/react-v15-rc1.html):

> React DOM: When specifying a unit-less CSS value as a string, a future version will not add px automatically. This version now warns in this case (ex: writing style=. (Unitless number values like width: 300 are unchanged.)